# Android galaxy tab options menu different?

Tags: android, options-menu, galaxy-tab

My friend tried my app with his new galaxy tab and it seems it is a little different than the emulator I tested it on.  His options menu for the app was dark instead of the white background and you could not really see any of the options and most of the app did not work properly.  I made the app on the 2.1 android update and am very stumped I tried searching for something about this but could not find anything.  Is there a way to modify to act accordingly if this happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Samsung modified a lot of standard themes and images. The only way to fix it, that I found, was to force my own theme and use my own images everywhere.

Comment: Not just Samsung does this; all devices with custom skins have this. The only ones that don't are the Nexus line and some AOSP-based ROMs like Cyanogenmod (though it can be themed to be changed).

Answer (score 1):

Since Android 2.3 the menu background has changed to black. But the general color palette for the icons you make shouldn't be that much different. See more here:
[Android Menu Design Guidelines](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_menu.html)

If you wish to have different icons for android version 2.3 and earlier versions put the icons for Android 2.3 and later in a resource folder with -v9 appended to the folder name. Example:
drawable-hdpi-v9

You should do the same thing with notification icons, as android 2.3 really made a big change to the way notification icons should look.

Btw, if you are looking for an easy way to make icons for your application, Roman Nurik's asset studio is really great: http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html